# Why adopt early?

Tags: windows, upgrade

Every time a new version of Windows comes out, I find myself asking why a company should start rolling it out immediately. There's likelihood for bugs that would be fixed in a service pack, so some would say its better to wait until a service pack is released. There's also the "if it ain't broke don't fix it" attitude, and the "users get confused", "supporting a new OS nightmare" point of view. But none of these seem to wash with me.

Thinking about it in a more holistic way, these just feel like excuses not to change the way the process is (eventually) handled so that such questions are irrelevant.

**I'd like to think early adoption is a good idea, but I can't explain why. Can you help? Now that MS are moving to an annual update cycle, will organisations have to change the way they think about such things?**

Comment: All answers will be extremely subjective, particularly based on the size of the companies. The larger you are, the more sensitive you are to call volume, and new operating systems mean: 1) more problems for people to find, 2) more imagined problems for people to find, 3) more time on ticket turnaround due to problems that haven't popped up before. Then there are the companies who have application deployment solutions that have to be tested. Suffice it to say, **there is no correct answer to this question**.

Comment: Isn't everyone's reasons going to be different?

Comment: Should this be closed then, since it's too broad and subjective?

Comment: I'd be more apt to go Community Wiki on it, personally (but, then again, I don't really have my finger on the "pulse" of the Server Fault community).

Comment: We don't put CW on Questions generally, this one really doesn't fit. I'm inclined to leave it open as it might not be the best question, but is attracting good answers. And I love Answers where people point out that IT exists to support "Business Goals" (mainly profitability) while denouncing "IT for IT sake".

Comment: Well only three more votes to go anyway, so don't hold back :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think of early adoption as a good or bad idea, per se. Functional, reliable systems that satisfy business needs are a good idea. Sometimes moving to new versions or products enhances reliability and functionality and creates new capabilities to enhance business value and, other times, it doesn't.

I make a case for updating to my Customers when there are compelling reasons. I have two basic items I look for:

- New features that the business can leverage to increase business productivity and efficiency, decreased support costs, etc.
- Risks associated with *not* upgrading (loss of support and exposure to outages, security vulnerabilities, etc)

I will make an appropriately detailed business case based on the total cost of the upgrade (licenses, hardware, implementation cost, etc) to state my case.

Sometimes there are risks to not upgrading (like, say, being unsupported). Many times, though, there are risks associated with early adoption, too. It's frustratingly difficult to quantify the risks associated with early adoption. It's pretty typical in the IT industry that new products don't always function as intended (the whole "wait for the first service pack" mentality didn't just spring up out of nothing). Manufacturers have varying track records for the reliability of their new products and, unfortunately, within a given manufacturer's product line that can often vary wildly (see the train-wreck that was "Symantec Endpoint Protection 11" compared to updates to "Backup Exec" at the same time period as an example). I always try to make the point that early adopters generally have the most risk. If you're able, do a pilot deployment and/or phased migration to minimize that risk.

I do think that blindly assuming that "new is better" is generally a *bad* idea. "New" implies some costs and those costs need to be justified. There's nothing that gives IT a black eye more quickly, in my opinion, than appearing to management to be bottomless pit to shovel money into. IT for IT's sake-- being an early-adopter because it just seems like a good idea-- has been a way that I've seen a number of IT organizations become regarded as a "bottomless pit".

Comment: Thanks for the advice, perhaps I'm just too keen for tomorrow to come today.

Comment: @john - Oh, don't get me wrong-- I'm all for early adoption in our test labs-- especially when it has minimal cost. I get really, really wary of changes to production environments, though, without business justification. I think it's part of the maturing of IT to try to look at everything from a business perspective *and* a technology perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Look for features you want.

In the current Windows 8 release, some things that might grab a network admin's attention:

- Updated Remote Desktop protocol, with improvements in performance, security, multi-monitor support, etc.
- Improved network file transfer performance (when paired with Server 2012)
- Computer accounts work with the new Active Directory recycle bin (when paired with Server 2012)
- Additional Group Policy controls
- Better touch support. This is not just for fancy laptops/tablets. It's also nice if you have classrooms or conference rooms with interactive white boards
- Improved Sync Center
- Out-of-the-box drivers for a newer set of devices (soon to include 3D printers)
- Improved start-up/shutdown times
- Improved power management

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not asking for version specific features. This is an ongoing problem and may continue to be. I want to understand why it exists.

Comment: The idea stands in general too. This might be a list for Win6.1, but Win6.0 was a fairly large improvement over 5.0 and same with 4.0. The beta Win6.2 shows some significant improvements already as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting early or late should be a decision made independently for each iteration because there are always many variables involved that change with time and situation.  As such, I always do the following:

> The decision to adopt a new version of a product should always be
>   treated just like the decision to adopt an entirely new product. 
>   Weigh the benefits vs. the time, effort, disruption and potential
>   pitfalls involved.  If the benefits outweigh the costs/downside, pull
>   the trigger on the upgrade, otherwise wait a bit and re-evaluate when
>   the variables change.

I hope this helps.  It's probably a bit more general than you were probably looking for, but every upgrade is unique and your business may be in a different state of readiness at each release as well.  This covers both.